# How do I create a legend for a layered line plot

Tags: vega-lite, vega, observablehq

Basically what I have is a line graph that is layered from several line graphs. Since each graph has only one line, there is no legend automatically generated, so what is the best way to get a legend for the chart? I have been considering trying to transform my dataset. This is weekly deaths total from the cdc from 2019-June 2020. The way the csv is arranged is each date for each state has a record with each disease type as it's own column and integers as the column values. So there isn't one field to chart, there are many, hence the layering. Any insights into how to solve this problem would be much appreciated! Here is my work so far:

https://observablehq.com/@justin-krohn/covid-excess-deaths

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a legend for a layered chart by setting the color encoding for each layer to a `datum` specifying what label you would like it to have. For example ([vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJghgLhIFygG4QDYFcCmBneBtUAHvAIwA0IAnsSeRQEzx0C+phjt1cAzLQ3MSzbcO7SnwAsgkETjiRs3vC5SZAVnk8x8VUwC6LEBgB2AYwD2YAJZGA5vCGgAZpYwow8aSHJQKABwweAI5oEEZQljDhiAFMBigQFBgATnigALYQSQDWHijWAeTG5la29pRlzq7ucJTU3n4BNcGh4ZGW0SAG5ihmKQjg0GhpHlSdsawgGdm5+V6GphbWdv0UFS5uIwz1-kEhYRHQ7THk3b1lkFBDm2N6TEA)):

```
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"x": 1, "y1": 1, "y2": 2},
      {"x": 2, "y1": 3, "y2": 1},
      {"x": 3, "y1": 2, "y2": 4},
      {"x": 4, "y1": 4, "y2": 3},
      {"x": 5, "y1": 3, "y2": 5}
    ]
  },
  "encoding": {"x": {"field": "x", "type": "quantitative"}},
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": "line",
      "encoding": {
        "y": {"field": "y1", "type": "quantitative"},
        "color": {"datum": "y1"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": "line",
      "encoding": {
        "y": {"field": "y2", "type": "quantitative"},
        "color": {"datum": "y2"}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use a [Fold Transform](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/fold.html) to pivot your data so that instead of manual layers, you can plot the multiple lines with a simple color encoding. For example ([vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJghgLhIFygG4QDYFcCmBneBtUAHvAIwA0IAnsSeRQEzx0C+phjt1cAzLQ3MSzbcO7SnwAsgkETjiRs3vC5SZAVnk8x8VUwC6LEFABOEAHZYAZgHsjAWzyhrKMHkrVFu8hBxxcIUxC2GCC0IPqeILYQRgDW8CAoAJamweQYpgDGVmDJAObwQo6JGM7xRORQFAAOwXAgAI5oZlCJMC2IwQYUBSAWxaV13RXVtQ1Npi1tiR0gBlkoNj19JS51AUEhhiPxpla2yaizTExAA)):

```
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"x": 1, "y1": 1, "y2": 2},
      {"x": 2, "y1": 3, "y2": 1},
      {"x": 3, "y1": 2, "y2": 4},
      {"x": 4, "y1": 4, "y2": 3},
      {"x": 5, "y1": 3, "y2": 5}
    ]
  },
  "transform": [{"fold": ["y1", "y2"], "as": ["name", "y"]}],
  "mark": "line",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "x", "type": "quantitative"},
    "y": {"field": "y", "type": "quantitative"},
    "color": {"field": "name", "type": "nominal"}
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I ended up doing some pre-processing in R and used the gather function there, which I think is like the fold transform you suggest.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if there's any way to customize the colors used in your first approach? I want to change the blue and orange to different ones.